# Google analytics dashboard in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, google-analytics

How to integrate google analytics dashboard into a modern SharePoint page? Please let me know.

Comment: You want to track SPO sites using Google Analytics? Or you want to display  aGA dashboard inside SPO?

Comment: @DenisMolodtsov Display a GA dashboard inside SPO. I am already tracking the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be injected into SharePoint modern page as a solution using SPFX extension. Hope this article-[How to add Google Analytics to the Modern SharePoint](https://sharepoint.handsontek.net/2017/12/21/how-to-add-google-analytics-to-the-modern-sharepoint/)-may help you, please take a reference to it.

Comment: but this is to get the data from the site not embedding the dashboard in a SharePoint page right? You still have to go to google analytics to see the dashboard, i was looking for showing the dashboard in sharepoint itself so that you dont have to log into google analytics everytime.